# How to return from HALT in LC3?

Tags: assembly, lc3

This picture is from the book "introduction to computing systems 3d edidtion".

[image]

I have highlighted in red what I am wondering about. Could you please tell me the answer to the authors question?

Comment: The classic [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and the tag for it here at StackOverflow is about being able to [decide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem) whether an algorithm will halt or stop (run to completion yielding a result) based on (static) analysis of the algorithm and some given input.  So, not the same thing as LC-3 restarting from halt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a trick question.  After that bit in the Machine Control Register is cleared, instruction processing ceases because the clock is stopped — so the answer is none, no instruction or trap can be used to restart the system.

Only an external mechanism can restart the clock once halted.

If an external mechanism were to restart the clock (presumably setting that bit in the MCR?), then the HALT trap will return to its caller — but calling programs absolutely do not expect this to happen!  There's generally no more code after a HALT trap, so no instructions to run, and often even, there's data there after a HALT (and it is nonsense to execute data) because of programmer's expectation that a HALT trap doesn't return.

The most reasonable way to restart the clock is to use a complete restart mechanism, which would boot the machine and load some program to run at its starting entry point.

Comment: Fun fact: the equivalent instruction on a real ISA, like x86's `hlt`, stops the clock *until the next external interrupt*.  So it's basically a wait-for-interrupt instruction.  Or something you can put in a loop to save power if you don't have any work to do at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have found that in an earlier chapter of the book, there was an exercise question about how we can return from HALT. This was before they talked about interrupts, but I found the solutions manual(and fortunately this was an odd-numbered exercise so there was an answer), and there they actually say that an interupt can start it again. There is also an appendix with a microarchitecture to the LC3, and I think(maybe with some slight modifications) that one can see that we are able to have the LC3 start again after an interrupt.